# How do I look up row values in another table's column?

Tags: sql

I have a table A and Table B

Table A

```
Student     Math    Science
1           65      38
2           72      99
3           83      85
4           95      91
5           49      20
6           60      80
```

Table B

```
Course      score_low   score_high  Mark
Math        0           50          D
Math        51          80          C
Math        81          90          B
Math        91          100         A
Science     0           50          D
Science     51          80          C
Science     81          90          B
Science     91          100         A
```

What I want to see is Joining Table a with Table B

```
Student     Math    Science     Math Mark   Science Mark
1           65      38          C           D
2           72      99          C           A
3           83      85          B           B
4           95      91          A           A
5           49      20          D           D
6           60      80          C           C
```

Comment: This makes no sense at all. How are they linked? How do you know that row 1;65;38 of Table A is linked with C and D (and which C and D)?

Comment: I don't think a join is what you are looking for [link] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)). You don't have common fields between the two.

Comment: @WadeRyan Actually the data can be joined, you can unpivot the data in tablea or you can join on tableb multiple times.

Answer (score 5):

Part of your problem is that your `tableA` is denormalized and you have a separate column for `Math` and `Science`.  One way to get the result would be to unpivot the data in `tableA` so you can easily join to `tableb`.  Once you have joined the data based on the course name and the score range, then you can use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the final result in separate columns:

```
select a.student,
  max(case when a.Course = 'math' then a.mark end) Math,
  max(case when a.Course = 'science' then a.mark end) science,
  max(case when a.Course = 'math' then b.mark end) MathMark,
  max(case when a.Course = 'science' then b.mark end) ScienceMark
from
(
  select student, math mark, 'Math' Course 
  from tablea
  union all
  select student, Science mark, 'Science' Course 
  from tablea
) a
inner join tableb b
  on a.Course = b.Course
  and a.mark >= b.score_low
  and a.mark <= b.score_high
group by a.student;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c307b/3).

Or this could be written using multiple joins on `tableb`:

```
select a.student,
  a.math,
  a.science,
  bMath.mark mathMark,
  bSci.mark ScienceMark
from tablea a
left join tableb bMath
  on a.math >= bMath.score_low
  and a.math <= bMath.score_high
  and bMath.course = 'Math'
left join tableb bSci
  on a.science >= bSci.score_low
  and a.science <= bSci.score_high
  and bSci.course = 'Science';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c307b/5).  Both will give a result:

```
| STUDENT | MATH | SCIENCE | MATHMARK | SCIENCEMARK |
-----------------------------------------------------
|       1 |   65 |      38 |        C |           D |
|       2 |   72 |      99 |        C |           A |
|       3 |   83 |      85 |        B |           B |
|       4 |   95 |      91 |        A |           A |
|       5 |   49 |      20 |        D |           D |
|       6 |   60 |      80 |        C |           C |
```

Comment: Nice i didn't see the correct data at first and i didn't fully understand the topicstarters question. But i see now it was a simple lookup query to match a garde.

Answer (score 0):

havent tried it yet, but something like this

```
select *, 
(select Mark from tableB where course='Math' and score_low >= a.Math and score_high <= a.Math), 

(select Mark from tableB where course='Science' and score_low >= a.Math and score_high <= a.Math) 
 from tableA a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.Student, a.Math, a.Science, bm.Mark as [Math Mark], bs.Mark as [Science Mark]
from TableA a 
    join TableB bm on a.Math between bm.score_low and bm.score_high
                and bm.Course = 'Math'
    join TableB bs on a.Science between bs.score_low and bs.score_high
                and bs.Course = 'Science'
order by a.Student;
```

This was written in T-SQL, as used on SQL Server.  If your version of SQL doesn't have a between clause you can change the code to:

```
    join TableB bm on a.Math >= bm.score_low 
                and a.Math <= bm.score_high
                and bm.Course = 'Math'
    join TableB bs on a.Science >= bs.score_low
                and a.Science <= bs.score_high
                and bs.Course = 'Science'
```

However, I notice the grade ranges are the same for both Math and Science.  Will these ranges change?  If not, or at least not frequently, it'd be easier to use a case statement:

```
select a.Student, a.Math, a.Science, 
    case 
        when a.Math between 0 and 50 then 'D'
        when a.Math between 51 and 80 then 'C'
        when a.Math between 81 and 90 then 'B'
        when a.Math between 91 and 100 then 'A'
        else 'X'
    end as [Math Mark], 
    case 
        when a.Science between 0 and 50 then 'D'
        when a.Science between 51 and 80 then 'C'
        when a.Science between 81 and 90 then 'B'
        when a.Science between 91 and 100 then 'A'
        else 'X'
    end as [Science Mark]
from TableA a 
order by a.Student;
```